# generating number between 1 to million syntax error

Tags: php

This code

```
<? php
$randdnumber = rand(1, 1000000);
echo "you won ".$randnumber."points";
?>
```

gives me error

> syntax error, unexpected '$randdnumber' (T_VARIABLE) in index.php

also how to add output of two function together something like ..

```
 You won [$randdnumber] also you won [$randdnumber2]
```

is it possible ?

Comment: If you defined those two variables it is possible. As for the error, it looks like you made a typo. `$randdnumber` (2 d's) over `$randnumber` (1 d)

Comment: `<?php` not `<? php`?

Answer (score 1):

FIXED

```
    <?php
    $randnumber = rand(1, 1000000);
    echo "you won ".$randnumber."points";
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**FIXED CODE**

```
    <?php
      $randdnumber = rand(1, 1000000);
      echo "you won ".$randdnumber."points";
    ?>
```

fix php tags and changed variable name

Answer (score 0):

The exact problem is your php open tag is having space and also variable name you assigned and echoed are different :

Please remove it and change it to

```
<?php
    $randdnumber = rand(1, 1000000);
     echo "you won ".$randdnumber."points";
?>
```